# Getting NuGet packages from Organizations repo

Tags: c#, nuget

I am fairly new to C# development and my organization has a location on one of their servers that contains nuget packages that were created by a past developer. I have the location of the packages mounted on my machine as a network location, when I try and add a new package source and browse to the location of the directory containing all of the .nupkg files and then browse for the packages in the NuGet Package Manager it comes up with no results. I have even downloaded the packages to my local machine and tried adding the source to the directory that is on my C: drive and still I get no packages to pick from. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the `Manage Packages for solution...` window? What do you have selected as the package source?

Comment: i had the same problem before ... after a long search ... it was about operating system witch had problems for network .... try to update your os and your vs ...

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so maybe put the package/dlls you want directly into your project

Comment: @bman I am not sure how to do that

Comment: So find the path for your project, it's usually something like source/repos/yourprojectname then manually paste the packages in the packages folder... Then you are going to need to add a reference to it

Answer (score 0):

NuGet has documentation on [installing packages and adding sources in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

Although, I'm not a fan of using the Visual Studio options page to add sources. When you add a source there, it's added to your user profile's `nuget.config` file, which means that all solutions on the same computer will use that source (unless the solution has it's own `nuget.config` file that uses `<clear />` to remove all inherited sources). It also means that if you share the project/solution, anyone else using the solution will not have the correct sources. So, it's best to add an `nuget.config` file next to the solution and set up the correct sources there. A quick way to get started is to use `dotnet new nugetconfig` from a command line, assuming you have the .NET Core SDK installed.